# Why PHP returns false in if condition when array_sum() value is 1?

Tags: php, array-sum

I am facing one weird issue, sum of array is 1 but when I checking it into the IF condition it returns false.

```
$array = array
(
    0 => 0.237,
    1 => 0.318,
    2 => 0.215,
    3 => 0.06,
    4 => 0.069,
    5 => 0.053,
    6 => 0.048
);

if(array_sum($array) != 1){
    echo "It's not one";
} else {
    echo "It's one"; 
}
```

Above code is returning **It's not one** instead of **It's one**.

Comment: Because floating point math.

Comment: How I need to resolve this issue? I have checked array_sum($arrays), It is showing 1.

Comment: Depends on how accurate it needs to be. You could use `round()`, `ceil()`, `floor()` or `bcmath` extension (and more) depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: I need to check sum of array values which must be 1 and my array is dynamic.

Comment: `array_walk($array, function(&$i) { $i *= 100; }); if(array_sum($array) != 100) { …`

Comment: Use `if ((string)array_sum($array) != 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
$sum=number_format(array_sum($array));
if($sum != 1){
    echo "It's not one";
} else {
    echo "It's one"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare float values without rounding them.
See more here >> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

You can do it as below,

```
$array = array
(
    0 => 0.237,
    1 => 0.318,
    2 => 0.215,
    3 => 0.06,
    4 => 0.069,
    5 => 0.053,
    6 => 0.048
);

if(round(array_sum($array)) != 1){
    echo "It's not one";
} else {
    echo "It's one"; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, But I need to check my values must be 1. So, I can't apply round on that.

Comment: in php, `floatval(1) == 1.0000000000000001`.So your sum value has to be rounded at least into 15 decimals

Comment: in your case rounding into 3 decimal places would be the best solution `round(array_sum($array), 3)`

Comment: It is working with if((float) trim(array_sum($array) != 1)

Comment: Great. only difference from rounding is you're doing it in 2 steps.First trim them cast.anyway this is working then cheers!

Comment: Yes, Thank you for look into this.